# Why do I obtain different output results with blast vs awk commands

Tags: fasta, shell, awk, blastn, multiple-sequence-alignment

I have an `awk` command that identifies 30 pb from two multifasta files.

When I used two input files:

- E.g. 100 sequences each, I get the same result with the `awk` command and `blastn` command.
- E.g. with 1,000 sequences each I get the same result with both commands.

**Question** However, when I increase the number of sequences to 10,000 I get different outputs, any idea why this could happend?

```
Command-#sequences-matches
awk      -100-       1
blastn   -100-       1
awk     -1000-      73
blastn  -1000-      73
awk     -10000-     8384
blastn  -10000-     8280
```

1. 

```
awk command:

BEGIN { wid = 30 }

sub(/^>/,"") { hdr=$1; next }

NR == FNR { a[hdr]=$0; next }

{

    for ( hdrA in a ) {

        strA  = a[hdrA]

        lgthA = length(strA)

        for ( idxA=1; idxA<=(lgthA - wid); idxA++ ) {

            substrA = substr(strA,idxA,wid)

            if ( index($0, substrA) ) {

                printf "[%s,%s]\n", hdrA, hdr

                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`awk -f tst.awk file_with_100seqs file_with_100seqsv2`

2. blastn command:

`blastn -query file_with_100seqs -subject file_with_100seqsv2 -out blastn_output_seqs1vs2_100.txt -word_size 30 -perc_identity 100 -outfmt "10 qseqid sseqid"`

The input files look like this:

#File1

```
>1  
TGATTGCATAACCACTTAACATCTTGTTTTATCTAAATAAAATTAAGCATGTTATCTTTTTGGGGCACTCCTGGGGCAGTAGATGCCAGTTGTTGATTCAGTATATCTACTTGTGACTGGTTATTATCCCGATTTTTTTAGTTTTAAGGTGTTGACATAGCCATCCATGCTCCATATACTGTATAGACCATCTGAGCGTT  
>2  
TGGGAAAACAGCATTCAGCGGTGGCTTATTCCTGCTAAGGATGTTGGCCGCATTCATGCTGAGCACAACCTCGACGGCCTGCTGAGGGGCGATTCGGCATCCCGCGCTGCCTTTATGAAGGCAATGGGAGAGGCAGGGCTACGCACCATCAACGAGATGCGACGAACGGACAACCTCCCGCCATTGCCGGGTGGCGATGT  
>3  
GAAATGGGAACCGCGAACATGCCTGCACATCCGTTTGTGCGACCCGCTTACGATACTCGCGAGGAAGAGGCCGCCAGCGTCGCCATTGCCAGGATGAATCAGGCTATTGATGAGGTATTGAGCAAGTGAATGAAGATAATATCTACGCCTTGCTTTCTCCCCTGGCAGAAGGACGGGTATATCCCTATGTTGCGCCATTA
```

#File2

```
>1  
TGATTGCATAACCACTTAACATCTTGTTTTATCTAAATAAAATTAAGCATGTTATCTTTTTGGGGCACTCCTGGGGCAGTAGATGCCAGTTGTTGATTCAGTATATCTACTTGTGACTGGTTATTATCCCGATTTTTTTAGTTTTAAGGTGTTGACATAGCCATCCATGCGGGAAGGTGCAGCATAATGTGCTTTGGATT  
>2  
TGAGTGCCCCATTTGTGAAGCAATAAAGTTCGGGTTCGCGCCAGCGGCAAGCGCCCAGCATGCACCGATTTTTTTAGTTTTAAGGTGTTGACATTAGGTATGTCGGGACTGGTATGCTTTCCTGTGTCGCAGCCCGGCGCGTCTCAATGCAGATTCCCATATCCTGTTCATCCATATACTGTATAGACCATCTGAGCGTT  
>3  
TACCTGAGCGATCGGTAATTTGCGGATTGAAGACAAAGGTGCAGGAATGAGTTTTTGTACGACCGTATTCGCGCAGCTTTACTTCAATTTTGTGCTGTTTGCTCAGCTTCGTGAAAGAGGCCTGACTTTTTAAAGCATCAATTGCTGGCTGCACAAGATGTATCACCCTGTCGGTTCCTGCCTGGGTTTTCGGCAGGGTG
```

Comment: Can you please tell us what you are trying to accomplish? It is not clear what your input data are, what you are searching for, and what the intended output is.